# Exception has occurred. LateError (LateInitializationError: Field 'notes' has not been initialized.)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, exception

[image]

[image]

[image]

class search extends StatefulWidget {
const search({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State createState() => _searchState();
}

class _searchState extends State {
String query = '';

late List notes;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(
title: Text("sdfs"),
centerTitle: true,
),
body: Column(
children: [
buildSearch(),
Expanded(
child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
itemCount: notes.length,
staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(2),
crossAxisCount: 4,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
final note = notes[index];

```
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => NoteDetailPage(noteId: note.id!),
                  ));
                },
                child: NoteCardWidget(note: note, index: index),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Should not post image instead of code snippet

Answer (score 1):

you have made the List notes `late` but seems you have used it without initializing it. You need to initialize it in `initState`, like this one-

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    notes = [];
  }
```